# Coefficients of a symmetric product of polynomials with root of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-polynomials, roots-of-unity, circulant-matrices

For number $n\ge2$, let $\xi$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

The [determinant of circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant) is a symmetric polynomial in $x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}$
$$f_n=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ξ^{ij}x_i$$
so after expansion, all coefficients are integer.

Is the following true?

> For prime number $n$, all coefficients of$$f_n-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_i^n$$are divisible by $n$.

Using [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) I verified it for $n=2,3,5,7$.

For $n=5$:

```
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x_:5')

f5 = prod(sum(exp(I*2*pi/5*j*i) * x[i] for i in (0..4)) for j in (0..4))
poly = expand(f5- sum(x[i]**5 for i in (0..4))).maxima_methods().rootscontract()
```

output:
$-5x_{0} x_{1}^{3} x_{2} + 5x_{0}^{2} x_{1} x_{2}^{2} + 5x_{0}^{2} x_{1}^{2} x_{3} - 5x_{0}^{3} x_{2} x_{3} - 5x_{1} x_{2}^{3} x_{3} + 5x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{3}^{2} + 5x_{0} x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} - 5x_{0} x_{1} x_{3}^{3} - 5x_{0}^{3} x_{1} x_{4} + 5x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} x_{4} - 5x_{0} x_{2}^{3} x_{4} - 5x_{1}^{3} x_{3} x_{4} - 5x_{0} x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} + 5x_{0}^{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} - 5x_{2} x_{3}^{3} x_{4} + 5x_{0} x_{1}^{2} x_{4}^{2} + 5x_{0}^{2} x_{2} x_{4}^{2} + 5x_{2}^{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + 5x_{1} x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2} - 5x_{1} x_{2} x_{4}^{3} - 5x_{0} x_{3} x_{4}^{3}$

```
poly/5 in ZZ[x]
```

output: True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We work in $K=\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$. The circulant matrix $J$ verifies $J^n=I_n.$ Since we are in characteristic $n$ this matrix $J$ only $1$ as eigenvalues. Now as it stands $\phi_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_kJ^k\in K[X_1,\dots,X_n] ,$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k^n=(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k)^n.$ Consider the matrix :  $$N:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k (J^k-I_n)$$
It is nilpotent, since $J^k$ are unipotent. Therefore $\phi_n = (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k)I_n +N$. Hence by taking determinants $$f_n\mod n =\det \phi_n=\det \left((\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k)I_n+ N\right)= (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_k)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k^n.$$
This translates to $f_n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X^n_k \equiv 0 $ in $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$.
Hope that helps.